# Resolving subdocument types with Spring Data and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm encountering an error with a Spring Data repository as it attempts to resolve a property expression:

```
public interface ContractRepository
    extends MongoRepository<Contract,String> {
    public List<Contract> findByCodeBindings(String binding);
}
```

Here's the relevant parts of `Contract`:

```
@Document(collection="CONTRACTS")
public class PersistentContract extends BaseContract {
    @PersistenceConstructor
    public PersistentContract(String name, Version version, Code code) {
        super(name, version, code);
    }
}
```

`Code` is an interface implemented by `CodeImpl`.  It contains a property `bindings`, which has a getter and setter in `Code`.  So the query's property expression is designed to find those contracts with a nested Code document containing a given binding.  So far, so good.

However, the problem is an `IllegalArgumentException` is getting thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property bindings found on my.company.Code!
 org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:225)
```

Debugging that section of code shows that Spring Data is picking apart the expression and determines there's a property of type `Code`.  However, because `Code` is an interface, it has no properties listed.

Is there a means to hint to Spring Data that either `Code` has this property or that `CodeImpl` is the actual type of the `code` property?  I'm surprised that the library doesn't attempt to parse the getters or setters of the interface.

This is using spring-data-commons 1.5.1.RELEASE and spring-data-mongodb 1.2.1.RELEASE.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to avoid interfaces at all in the persistent object.  So `BaseContract` became the following:

```
public abstract class BaseContract<T extends Code> {
    public abstract T getCode();
}
```

And `PersistentContract` was implemented in terms of concrete classes:

```
public class PersistentContract extends BaseContract<CodeImpl> {
}
```

This seems to strike the right balance between coding against interfaces in the base class and satisfying Spring Data's need for concrete classes.