# Spring -Data MongoDB issue with field which is an interface

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring-Data for MongoDB:

Version information - org.mongodb.mongo-java-driver version 2.10.1, 
org.springframework.data.spring-data-mongodb version 1.2.1.RELEASE.

I have a case that's similar to the one defined in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886999/sd-mongodb-polymorphism-in-subdocument), which is (sorry for the formatting...):

> I just started developing some app in Java with spring-data-mongodb and came across some issue that I haven't been able to solve:
>
> I have a couple of document beans like this:

```
@Document(collection="myBeanBar")
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
    String id;
    Foo foo;
    // More fields and methods ... 
}

@Document
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    String id;
    String someField;
    // some more fields and methods ...
}
```

> And I have
>       a repository class with a method that simply invokes a find similar to
>       this:

```
public List<? extends Bar> findByFooField(final String fieldValue) {
    Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("foo.someField").is(fieldValue));
    return getMongoOperations().find(query, BarImpl.class);
}
```

> Saving a Bar works just fine, it would save it in mongo along with the
>   "_class" attribute for both Foo and Bar. However, finding by some
>   attribute in Foo would throw an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
property someField found on test.Foo!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getPath(QueryMapper.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getTargetProperty(QueryMapper.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)
```

The solution that was given was to use the @TypeAlias annotation on the abstract class, which told the framework to use a specific implementation (in this case *FooImpl*).

In my case, I have **interface** members, instead of **abstract** members:

```
@Document(collection="myBeanBar")
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
    String id;
    IFoo foo;
    // More fields and methods ...
}
```

I'm very reluctant to put an annotation on the interface *IFoo* that will give a default implementation, instead I'd like to tell the framework what this **field's** default implementation in the context of the implementing *BarImpl* class, similar to @JsonTypeInfo:

```
@Document(collection="myBeanBar") 
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
    String id;    

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, defaultImpl = FooImpl.class)
    IFoo foo; 

    // More fields and methods ... 
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241901/resolving-subdocument-types-with-spring-data-and-mongodb), which more or less says to avoid using interfaces. but I'd be happy to know if there's no better option.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Spring Data MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Right, I added the version information - org.mongodb.mongo-java-driver version 2.10.1, org.springframework.data.spring-data-mongodb version 1.2.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Feels like you stumbled over https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-311. Do you have Spring Data Commons 1.5.1 on the classpath. This is the version the bug was fixed in.

Comment: Hey @OliverGierke, yes - that's the version I have in my path.
Thanks for the link, seems like I can't fix this while still using interfaces, so I had to use the implementing class instead.

I hope they fix it sometime soon.

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up using a wrapper around the class I wanted. For example, class Thing has a Foo and a Bar (but not both), then use Thing to persist. On the way back get a thing.isFoo(); and thing.getFoo()

Comment: Could you start adding your package `org.springframework.data` in debug ? You will be able to see the generated query and compare this query with your schema in your mongo.

Answer (score 10):

My problem is similar to the question, but the exception thrown is a bit different:

```
Could not instantiate bean class [class name]: Specified class is an interface
```

This happens when one of the fields of my DB class is declared as an interface. Saving this field is fine but exception thrown when reading it from MongoDB. Finally I found the solution that makes use of `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`.

**TWO** steps to do, 1. construct a class that implements `Converter`; 2. register the converter in the servlet context. And YES, you don't have to modify any existing code, such as adding annotation.

Below is my model class, where the field `Data` is an interface:

```
@Document(collection="record")
public class Record {
    @Id
    private String id;

    // Data is an interface
    private Data data;

    // And some other fields and setter/getter methods of them
}
```

The converter:

```
@ReadingConverter
public class DataReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, Data> {
    @Override
    public Data convert(DBObject source) {
        // Your implementation to parse the DBObject,
        // this object can be BasicDBObject or BasicDBList,
        // and return an object instance that implements Data.

        return null;
    }
}
```

The last thing to do is to register the converter, my configuration is in xml:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

<mongo:db-factory mongo-ref="mongo" dbname="example" />

<mongo:mapping-converter>
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <beans:bean class="com.example.DataReadConverter" />
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<beans:bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter" />
</beans:bean>
```

Deploy the application and try again. It should properly parse the DBObject from MongoDB on the interface field.

The version of my Spring MongoDB application is : spring-*-4.1.0 and spring-data-mongodb-1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message as @victor-wong

> `Could not instantiate bean class [class name]: Specified class is an interface`

The following code solves the problem with
`Spring Boot 2.3.2` and `spring-data-mongodb 3.0.2`

The converter:

```java
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter;

@ReadingConverter
public class DataReadConverter implements Converter<Document, Data> {

    @Override
    public Data convert(Document source) {

        return new DataImpl(source.get("key"));
    }
}
```

The last thing to do is to register the converter

```java
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(
                List.of(
                        new DataReadConverter()
                )
        );
    }
```

Additional information may be found here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2391

Answer (score 1):

While the solution with converter provided in other answers will work, it will require you to write a converter for every polymorphic filed. This is tedious and error-prone as it requires you to keep those converters in mind each time you add a new polymorphic field or change existing models.

Instead of writing a converter you can just configure type mappings. Moreover, you can make it work automagically. Here's how:

1. First we’re going to need [the reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). Pick the latest version for the build tool of your choice [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections).

   For example with Gradle:

   ```
   implementation("org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2")
   ```
2. Now we’re going to need a small extension to [`DefaultMongoTypeMapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/6e4d463053dec77d7ae9dd2e2bcf3ae91ea8ea8e/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java) to make it easy to configure and instantiate. Here’s how it would look in Kotlin:

   ```kotlin
   class ReflectiveMongoTypeMapper(
       private val reflections: Reflections = Reflections("com.example")
   ) : DefaultMongoTypeMapper(
       DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY,
       listOf(
           ConfigurableTypeInformationMapper(
               reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(TypeAlias::class.java).associateWith { clazz ->
                   getAnnotation(clazz, TypeAlias::class.java)!!.value
               }
           ),
           SimpleTypeInformationMapper(),
       )
   )
   ```

   where `com.example` is either your base package or the package with MongoDB models.

   This way we will find all classes annotated with `@TypeAlias` and register alias to type mappings.
3. Next we'll need to adjust the app's mongo configuration a bit. The configuration has to extend [`AbstractMongoClientConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory-java) and we need to override method `mappingMongoConverter` to make use of the mapper we created before. It should look like this:

   ```kotlin
   override fun mappingMongoConverter(
       databaseFactory: MongoDatabaseFactory,
       customConversions: MongoCustomConversions,
       mappingContext: MongoMappingContext,
   ) = super.mappingMongoConverter(databaseFactory, customConversions, mappingContext).apply {
       setTypeMapper(ReflectiveMongoTypeMapper())
   }
   ```
4. Done!

Now all alias to type mappings will be registered automatically on context startup and all your polymorphic fields will work just fine. No need to write and maintain converters.

You can check the [full code example on GitHub](https://github.com/monosoul/spring-data-mongo-issue/tree/reflective-type-mapping).

Also, here's a blog post where you can read about the root cause of this issue as well as check other ways to solve it (in case you don't want to rely on reflection): https://blog.monosoul.dev/2022/09/16/spring-data-mongodb-polymorphic-fields/

Comment: Thank you @andrei-nevedomskii! Your solution with ConfigurableTypeInformationMapper on top of reflections library really works for polymorphic fields. Out of the box Spring Data supports only TypeAlias for Documents but fields I had to keep with default class names because the DefaultMongoTypeMapper don't see the TypeAlias on classes we use for Fields. Finally I can get rid of full class names from our database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with polimorphic deserialization. Basically I was importing data from two sources (REST API and ETL). The REST API imports with Spring Data were ok because they had the "_class" field so deserialization was not an issue. But the ETL imported data did not have the "_class" fields so when deserializing into the interface it did not know which concrete class to use.

I did try to extends the DefaultMongoTypeMapper, but that did not work because I was trying to map a field that did not exist in the Mongo Document.

So, the solution that worked for me was to intercept the deserialization between the moment the Document reaches the app but before deserialization starts. At this moment I can simply verify if the "_class" field exists, and if not I identify the type of the document and add the "_class" field with the corresponding concrete class.

This is done by overriding the **onAfterLoad**() of the **AbstractMongoEventListener**.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class WrapperRepositoryListener extends 
AbstractMongoEventListener<Data> {
    @Override
    public void onAfterLoad(AfterLoadEvent<Data> event) {
         Document field = Document)event.getDocument().get(ROOT_FIELD);
         final String type = String.valueOf(field.get("type")).toLowerCase();

         switch (type) {
            case TYPE -> field.put("_class", CLASSNAME);
            default -> log.debug("Type is not supported: " + type);
         }
}
```

}

I hope this helps anyone who lands on this page.

Answer (score -2):

This is really bad idea to define interfaces as field in data object.

Interface means possibility of some object to do something, but don't provide any information about fields. Do you really need to use interfaces? Can you avoid this? Even using abstract class definition will be better idea.

P.S. off course, my answer can't be marked as correct answer in any case.